# Hard wrap in Doom Emacs

Tags: doom, wrapping

I'm trying Doom Emacs and immediately miss my hard wrap after 80 cols such as

```
(setq-default fill-column 80)
(setf fill-column 80)
(add-hook 'latex-mode-hook #'auto-fill-mode)
(add-hook 'prolog-mode-hook #'auto-fill-mode)
```

Would anyone know how I can implement such hard wrap rules in Doom Emacs? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean `(visual-line-mode t)` ?  This will wrap lines without changing the contents of the buffer.
By contrast, `(auto-fill-mode t)` will insert line breaks at the fill-column, as one types.
To wrap already-existing paragraphs, you may use `M-x fill-paragraph`, typically bound to `M-q`.

In your example code, your hooks might be improved by using `turn-on-auto-fill` as recommended in the [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoFillMode).  For example,
`(add-hook 'prolog-mode-hook 'turn-on-auto-fill)`

Comment: Please expand on why this an answer to the question.  IIUC, the OP is asking for hard (not visual) wrapping.

Comment: @FranBurstall, thank you for the clarifying suggestion.  I've edited my post to add extra detail, which I hope helps.